# Power BI relative date slicer auto refresh

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have a Power BI report where we have added a relative date slicer like this:

[image]

The Dates are coming from a delta table dimdate.

Here's what we want to achieve.

- End Date will always be todays date.
- Start Date will always be 3 months before todays date.

We have added the condition for the End date to be always be today. But are not able to dynamically populate the Start Date.

Is there any way we can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply a relative date filter on the visual. Click on the item then look at filters to the right, and filter on relative date for last three months.

[image: Apply filter here]

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use a relative date filter since the users want to filter the dates as per their wish within the last 3 months. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add your date column into the column and go to filters and add relative date.[image]

Comment: Adding a column seems a little overkill since OP specified it was coming from a time dim.